# How do I format Google Chart data to show a count of items, but be filterable by year

Tags: javascript, json, charts, google-visualization

Hopefully this is appropriate for stackexchange.  If not, my apologies.

Anyway, I have a set of data that is essentially a list of projects, the person tied to each project, and a year in which the project was started.  What I'd like to do is render a bar chart that shows a total count of projects per individual, but somehow maintain the year in which an individual project was started so I can create a slider filter.

That sounds confusing, writing it out.  The data looks like this:

```
[
    ['Project','PM','Year'],
    ['PRJ0001','John Doe','2012'],
    ['PRJ0002','John Doe','2012'],
    ['PRJ0003','Jackie Johnson','2013'],
    Etc, etc,
]
```

I have no problem creating a count by project manager name, but I "lose" the year as a metric on which I can filter.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: please add to your post the *code* you use to a) count them (loosing other data) and showing that in your chart and b) create a chart that somehow (how?) uses the data. It sounds like the question is more about correct code writing, not data formatting

Comment: That would be an incorrect assumption.  It's not about correct code writing, it is absolutely about the how the data needs to be formatted, as @WhiteHat picked up on, below.  I could post my code, but it wouldn't have helped answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

draw each control separately

use `data.group` to get counts per person and draw chart

draw the slider with the original data  (need to change column type for `NumberRangeFilter`)

redraw the chart on slider `'statechange'`
using slider low / high values to build a view using `getFilteredRows`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Project','PM','Year'],
      ['PRJ0001','John Doe',2012],
      ['PRJ0002','John Doe',2012],
      ['PRJ0003','John Doe',2012],
      ['PRJ0004','John Doe',2013],
      ['PRJ0005','Jackie Johnson',2012],
      ['PRJ0006','Jackie Johnson',2013],
      ['PRJ0007','Jackie Johnson',2014]
    ]);

    var options = {
      height: 400,
      hAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0,
          max: 5
        }
      }
    };

    drawChart(data);

    var slider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
      controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
      containerId: 'filter_div',
      dataTable: data,
      options: {
        filterColumnIndex: 2,
        ui: {
          format: {pattern: '0'}
        }
      }
    });

    google.visualization.events.addListener(slider, 'statechange', function () {
      var range = slider.getState();
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 2,
        minValue: range.lowValue,
        maxValue: range.highValue
      }]));
      drawChart(view);
    });

    slider.draw();

    function drawChart(dataTable) {
      var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
        dataTable,
        [1],
        [{column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.count, type: 'number', label: 'Count'}]
      );

      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(dataGroup, options);
    }
  },
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="filter_div"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Absolutely.  I'd just stumbled on the grouping stuff and was about to try it.  Thanks!