# Javascript Chart Rows of Unique Values

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, analytics

I am trying to graph website visitor analytical data using JavaScript, and I have been unable to find an efficient method or library available to help me achieve this easily. The data we have looks like this:

```
[[user job, url, date accessed],
 [user job, url, date accessed],
 [user job, url, date accessed]...]
```

I would like to create a pie chart or column chart showing how many people of each job type are visiting each url with the ability to filter by date range. I have looked at libraries like Google Charts, charts.js, chartist.js, but I can't find a way in any of these libraries to graph based on how many times a value appears in the rows. Does anyone know of a library that would make this easy/achievable or how to do this with any of the libraries I mentioned?

Comment: you can use google charts' [`group()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method to get counts -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38851678/5090771) which uses `group()` along with a range filter...

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you!