# Adding filters and charting the results in Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a [Water Usage Sample Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQTmYteohmVxiBReIyh_tRuOLIx6CXwgw0MuNw5jTTw/edit?usp=sharing) with *Month*, *Day*, *Time*, *Usage*, and *Gallons* columns.

I'd like to build a dashboard with a *Month filter*, *Day filter*, *Usage filter*, *Column Chart* and *Pie Chart*. By default (with no filter selections made), I'd like the column chart to display a sum of gallons by month and the pie chart to display the total usage breakdown.

If a specific month is selected in the *Month filte*r, I'd like the column chart to then display the sum of gallons for each day within that month and the pie chart to display the usage breakdown for that month. If a specific month and day is selected in the *month filter* and *day filter*, then I would like the column chart to then display each *"gallons"* entry by time for that month/day and the pie chart to display the usage breakdown for that month/day. If a specific usage is selected in the *usage filter*, I'd like the column chart to operate in the same manner as previously described, while only factoring the data for that specific usage. The pie chart would obviously just show 100% of that usage.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stringpark/zt2n4x9p/1/) I've been working on.

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
var opts = {sendMethod: 'auto'};
// Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQTmYteohmVxiBReIyh_tRuOLIx6CXwgw0MuNw5jTTw/gviz/tq?sheet=Sheet1&headers=1&range=A1:E2000', opts);

// Send the query with a callback function.
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}
function handleQueryResponse(response) {

if (response.isError()) {
alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
return;
}

var data = response.getDataTable();

var columnData = google.visualization.data.group(data, [{
    column: 1,
    type: 'date'
}], [{
    column: 4,
    label: 'Gallons',
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    type: 'number'
}]);

 var pieData = google.visualization.data.group(data, [{
    column: 3,
    type: 'date'
}], [{
    column: 4,
    label: 'Gallons',
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
    type: 'number'
}]);

// Set chart options
var options = {
    'title': 'WaterUsage',
        'width': 400,
        'height': 300
};

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var columnChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
columnChart.draw(columnData, options);

var pieChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
pieChart.draw(pieData, options);
```

This was mainly derived from this [thread](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/Z8Q8HNkxSwg).  Any ideas?

Comment: [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38851678/5090771) of using a filter and it's value to aggregate data and draw a chart

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat, I'll have a look at that.