# Google Charts One Control

Tags: google-visualization, dashboard

How can i make one control with multiple Charts but different data?

My code so far:

```
var overallDurationComparionLineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'overallDurationChartDiv',
    dataTable: overallDurationComparionLineChartData,
  });

  var enqueuedDurationComparionLineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'LineChart',
    containerId: 'enqueuedDurationChartDiv',
    dataTable: enqueuedDurationComparionLineChartData,
  });

   var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'control_div',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {'labelStacking': 'vertical', chartType: 'LineChart', snapToData: false},
        }
    });      

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  dashboard.bind(control, [overallDurationComparionLineChart, enqueuedDurationComparionLineChart]);
  dashboard.draw();
```

I know `dashboard.draw();` requires a `DataTable` (or `DataView`).

And if call it without any parameters there is no error but the the dashboard and its content isn't called either.
So how can i make it work?

Comment: there are a couple options 1) use one data table with all columns needed and set `view` property on the wrappers to exclude columns and / or rows 2) don't use a dashboard, instead use the `'statechange'` event and values from the control to drive the other charts --> [basic example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38851678/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat thx i'll try your suggestions