# Google Charts Filtered Table populate chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Looking at google chart example where a pie chart is displayed based on the results of a filtered google chart table. Essentially, I want the pie chart to be redrawn every time a filter is changed.

The reason is because there doesn't seem to be a way to sum or count the original datatable based on the filter. However, I do know this is possible by taking the filtered google table data.

If someone could point me to a good example, it would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38851678/5090771)...

Comment: Thank you very much. Figured it out bound filters and table to dashboard. Add listener for statechange on the date, grab the datatable, redraw pie chart.